# NodeJS Gremlin Queries

Tags: node.js, orientdb, gremlin

I'm currently building a Nodejs microservice that submits graph traversal queries to an OrientDB. I was wondering if Gremlin queries are supported in the standard orientjs db.query() method, or if I need to do it all with SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are supported. You can fire gremlin query

```
db.query('g.V()', { language : "gremlin", class : "com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.gremlin.OCommandGremlin"}).then(function(res){
        console.log(res);
    })
```